# Displaying image stored with image name

Tags: php, mysql

I have stored a image name in database this way, and I am not sure if the image name is inserted in it or not. However, I can see something of 14 B in blob type of image column.

```
$newImageSubmitted = isset( $_FILES['image'] );

if ( $newImageSubmitted ) 
{


    include_once "uploader.class.php";

    $uploader = new Uploader( "image" );

    $uploader->saveIn("img");

    $fileUploaded = $uploader->save();

}


$db = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","learndb");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed this is the error: " . $db->connect_error);
}

if($fileUploaded)
{
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO studentrecords (Name, email, Phone, school,dob,father,feereceived,due,image) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

if($stmt)
{
     $stmt->bind_param("ssisssiis",$name,$email,$phone,$school,$dob,$father,$feereceived,$due,$fileUploaded);
   $stmt->execute();
    include_once"viewstudentrecords1.php";
    $out="<center>information entered.</center>";
        echo "$out";
}
```

but displaying image this way is not working for me:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $myrow['image'] ).'"/ width="200" height="200">';
```

uploader.class.php

```
<?php

class Uploader {
private $filename;
private $fileData;
private $destination;

public function __construct( $key ) {
$this->filename = $_FILES[$key]['name'];
$this->fileData = $_FILES[$key]['tmp_name'];
}
public function saveIn( $folder ) {
$this->destination = $folder;
}
public function save(){
$folderIsWriteAble = is_writable( $this->destination );
if( $folderIsWriteAble ){
$name = "$this->destination/$this->filename";
if($succes = move_uploaded_file( $this->fileData, $name ))
{
    return $name;
}


} else {
trigger_error("cannot write to $this->destination");
$succes = false;
}
return $succes;
}
}
```

Comment: So you have stored a _file name_ only? Trying to create a data URI by base64-encoding the _file name_ does of course not make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: @CBroe previously i store image itself in the database so i used that code to display. Now what??

Comment: Well how would you normally embed an image into an HTML document, if you have the image’s URL path only …?

Comment: Ok. Is it this `'<img src= " .$myrow[ 'image'] . " >';`

Comment: Is it? You tell us. We don’t know if you saved a full/relative URL path, or the image file name only, so that you have to prefix it with the correct path …

Comment: @CBroe still i don't get it.

Comment: What is the exact value you have stored in your database (example please)? Does it correspond 1:1 to a URL path that can be requested via HTTP? If not, and it needs an additional path component before the image name you have stored, then you need to output that as well.

Comment: @CBroe ok. i have edited the question. that is how i uploaded image in a directory. and inserted that image name to database and trying to display that image.

Comment: Maybe add into your question one example image blob in your DB, and the code for getting the image. The code for inserting the image into the DB is not that essential to put in your question. In this way, it will be easier to get answers, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this line:

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $myrow['image'] ).'"/ width="200" height="200">';
```

It should be `/"` instead of `"/` to escape quotes.